# Get Base address of UART registers

Tags: linux-device-driver, uart, pci-e

- I'm using PCI card which opens two serial ports(UART).Developing driver for same.
- For doing operation on UART,i need to know **base address** from where i can shift and access uart configuration register(exa.LCR,IER,LSR,...etc.)
- Using which function i can get UART base address? or In datasheer where it is mentioned?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard port addresses are:

Standard port addresses are:

COM1 0x3F8 (1016)
 COM2 0x2F8 (760)
 COM3 0x3E8 (1000)
 COM4 0x2E8 (744)

Additional port addresses are:

COM5 0x3E0 (992)
 COM6 0x2E0 (736)
 COM7 0x338 (824)
 COM8 0x238 (568)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Intel® 82547EI Gigabit Ethernet Controller Data sheet :

> 10.1.1.1 Memory-Mapped Access to Internal Registers and Memories The internal registers and memories can be accessed as direct
>   memory-mapped offsets from the Base Address Register 0 (BAR0). The
>   appropriate offset for each specific internal register is described in
>   this section.

So I think that your card needs to be enumerated first by U-Boot or Linux.
Then you can access your card internal registers as offsets to the BAR0 address (from U-Boot or Linux).